# Export database from a remote server into a specific folder on my computer

Tags: php, mysql, database, shell, command-line-interface

I'm having trouble with a database export that is too big for phpmyadmin to handle.

I'm curious what the syntax would be for exporting a mysql database from a remote server and getting the export file into a specific folder on my own computer, all using the command line.

Say the database name is: mydb 
Say the remote server's ip is: 123.456.789.101 
Say my username is: tic
Say my password is: toc
Say the folder i want the mysql dump transferred into is my downloads folder, and say I am on a windows 7 pc.

unix/linux command solutions are welcome. Bonus points for solutions that work on microsoft.

Comment: Use `mysqldump` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run

`mysqldump -h yourhostname -u youruser -p yourdatabasename > C:\your\file\path.sql`

-h connects you to the remote servers IP so you can dump the data locally, as long as your user has the correct privileges and you can connect remotely to your database server.

However, you may need to ssh into your server first. If you are running windows, Download [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and connect to your host from this tool.

Once on remote server execute: >`mysqldump -u youruser -p yourdbname > /your/file/path.sql`

After that, download a ftp client tool like [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) or [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) and transfer (copy) the .sql file from your remote host onto your local host.

You can read more [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25599/mysql-db-import-export-command-line-in-windows) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-mysql-database-remote-server.html).

Comment: That is assuming the host excepts connections from outside the internal network it's on. Normally this is not the case, so he would need instructions on export remotely and then download.

Comment: Just expand on logging in to the server over ssh, dumping to file, then scp'ing that file down. Or alternately using a tunnel so that he can connect from with mysladmin running locally to the remote server.

Comment: On the **remote** machine that you have ssh'ed in to yes, but that doesnt mean you can connect directly to mysql from your **local** machine. You typically need to ssh in to the server first and run it from that box.